# javascript not recognizing 1 var >= another

Tags: javascript, jquery, integer

so, my problem here is that my code seems to be recognizing that 100 is < 2000, but its not recognizing that 200 < 1000

heres my code (i also use jquery as a framework FYI)

```
$('.filter-price').submit(function(e) {

    var alert_message = '';
    var price_from = $('.filter-price #price_from').val();
    var price_to = $('.filter-price #price_to').val();

    if (isNaN(price_from))
    {
        alert_message += "Price from must be a number, i.e. 500\n";
        $('.filter-price #price_from').val('From');
    }

    if (isNaN(price_to))
    {
        alert_message += "Price to must be a number, i.e. 500\n";
        $('.filter-price #price_to').val('To');
    }

    if (!isNaN(price_from) && !isNaN(price_to) && (price_from >= price_to))
    {
        alert_message += "Price from must be less than price to\n";
        $('.filter-price #price_from').val('From');
        $('.filter-price #price_to').val('To');
    }

    if (alert_message != '')
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(alert_message);
    }

});
```

i've tried using parseInt() on the vars which fixes nothing.

Comment: Form control values are always strings (except if you are using jQuery, which might return an array for a multiple select, or a Number according to the documentation but I think that is an error). So '200' is greater than '1000' when compared as strings.

Comment: You sure about the parseInt thing? It *really* looks like it's doing a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, in your error messages you should be saying "e.g." rather than "i.e.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you really need to do this way:

```
var price_from = parseInt($('.filter-price #price_from').val(), 10);
var price_to = parseInt($('.filter-price #price_to').val(), 10);
```

Look the result on chrome console:

```
'200' >= '1000'
true

200 >= 1000
false
```

And if you don't want to limit the numbers to int, replace `parseInt(val, 10)` to `parseFloat(val)`

Comment: I didn't think the `,10` argument was necessary, but that bit me a few times for inputs with leading zeros being interpreted as octal.

Comment: that's why I always put it. ;)

Comment: Or better yet, forget `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` and use the [unary + operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_(Unary_Plus)) - unless you _want_ a value like "12xyZ" entered by the user to be treated as "12" rather than giving an error.

Answer (score 2):

parseInt works for me. Not sure what was incorrect for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/98Bzn/1

```
var price_from = parseInt($('.filter-price #price_from').val());
var price_to = parseInt($('.filter-price #price_to').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Where have you tried using parseInt()? It seems to me that it's interpreting your values as strings rather than numbers, so you need to coerce them into the correct data type.

I would do this:

```
function convertCurrencyToNumber(value) {
    return Number(value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
}

...

var price_from = convertCurrencyToNumber($('.filter-price #price_from').val());
var price_to = convertCurrencyToNumber($('.filter-price #price_to').val());
```

It appears you're using currency, so the above will convert to a decimal for database storage or whatever else you're doing.